# Access/read low-level WiFi network packets in Android?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm trying to  access to raw data of a wifi packet in Android. If i use wifimanager only have access to BSSID, SSID and RSSI, but I need to access to time, address, etc. data on the packet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could look and see if you find a port of libpcap to Android. Would assume it requires root privileges though

Comment: In case of most modern wifi drivers a monitor interface needs to be created to access low-level frames. This somewhat depends on the exact driver used, though.